# Accessing a @Singleton from an @Entity without using @Inject/@EJB

Tags: java, ejb, domain-driven-design

I'm using Domain-Driven Design (I think!) and I have a requirement to access some global properties. I have my @Singleton thus:

```
@Singleton
public class MyProperties {
    private Properties props;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize()
    {
        try {
            props.load(new FileInputStream("my.properties"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String getProperty(String propertyName)
    {
        return props.getProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

I would like to do this:

```
@Entity(name="MYENTITY")
public class MyEntity {
    @Inject private MyProperties props;
    void doSomething()
    {
        String myProp = props.getProperty("my-prop");
        // ...etc...
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work - `props` is `null`, and anyway sites tell me [not to do that](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/03/04/How-not-to-inject-services-in-entities), and I should [use a Service Locator instead](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator), but that all smells of using JNDI lookup which [EJB 3.x kills off](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/service-locator/?source=archives).

My plan might be to try this sort of thing:

```
@WebListener
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{
    @Inject private MyProperties props;
    private MyServletContextListener theInstance;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        theInstance = this;
    }

    static public MyServletContextListener theInstance() { return theInstance; }
    public MyProperties getProperties() { return props; }
}
```

Does this make sense, or am I barking up the wrong tree, or do I just have some silly bug in my code?

**EDIT**: Note that I am using vanilla Java EE with CDI, JPA, etc, no Spring.

**EDIT2**: I see that CDI Best Practises say one should [add the @Vetoed annotation to all persistent entities](https://github.com/cdi-spec/cdi-spec.org/blob/master/_faq/integration/201-why-is-veto-a-best-practice-for-persistent-jpa-entities.asciidoc). Currently my application flow control is from a `@MessageBean` through a series of `@Entity`s - is this a design smell?

Comment: IMHO accessing services from an entity is a somewhat awkward design, i.e. data (which entities represent) accesses business logic (which your services represent). Depending on what your needs are I'd most probably move the logic to a service or store the data in the entity, e.g. by referencing a configuration entity of some sort.

Comment: Btw, the service locator pattern is not dead it's just less often needed. :)

Comment: Why don't you listen to the advice given in the linked blogpost (to not inject/user service lookup in entities)?

Comment: "Global properties" are an application-level concern.  Your application should initialize entities with the respective value (that might be contained in the properties files) upon creation or their life-time.  I agree with @Thomas, that accessing `MyProperties` from the entities is awkward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I cracked out my venerable [Gang of Four book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) and realised that I have a Visitor pattern here, which is particularly useful as my `@Entity`s form a hierarchy. So, I will add code like this:

```
public class DoSomethingVisitor extends EntityVisitor {
    @Inject private MyProperties props;

    @Override
    void visit(MyEntity entity)
    {
        String myProp = props.getProperty("my-prop");
        if(entity.getValue().equals(myProp))
        //...or whatever...
    }
}
```

And:

```
@Entity(name="MYENTITY")
public class MyEntity {
    void Accept(EntityVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

This solution also allows me to get rid of a `logger` parameter that I was passing around the `doSomething()` calls, and my business logic is now out of the `@Entity`s and into a place where I can do injections.

Answer (score 0):

First, any your entities are NOT in spring application context, so, any beans of spring can not inject into your entities!
Second, If you really want to do this, please add:

```
<context:spring-configured />
```

into your spring configuration, then add @Configurable at the MyEntity class!

Comment: please refer to: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch07s08.html

Comment: You might want to add that comment to your answer in order to keep it all in one place. :)

Comment: Oh and btw, the OP didn't say he used Spring at all - so I'd assume EJB + JPA + CDI here, i.e. plain JavaEE 6+.

Comment: no matter spring or ejb, the error root is: user's entities won't managered by spring or ejb container!

Comment: That's true, but telling the OP how to do that in Spring wouldn't help him if he's not using Spring at all.

Comment: Yes, I'm not using Spring, but I do have my `META-INF/beans.xml` with `bean-discovery-mode="all"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you chosen a javaee way that I suppose that using of `@EntityListener` annotation above entity would be preferred in this case. How it works. Define a listener class with some methods annotated with for example `@PostConstruct` or `@PrePersist`  :

```
    public class DoSomethingVisitor {

     @PrePersist  
     void visit(MyEntity entity)
    {
        String myProp = props.getProperty("my-prop");
        if(entity.getValue().equals(myProp))
        //...or whatever...
    }

    }
```

And define this class in annotation of the entity:

```
@Entity(name="MYENTITY")
@EntityListeners(value = {DoSomethingVisitor.class})
public class MyEntity {
    void Accept(EntityVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

All the best patterns already included in javaee box!

Comment: You can't inject `props` into `DoSomethingVisitor` for the same reason you can't inject it in the entity.